# MySQL Using index when joining a Function

Tags: mysql, indexing

I've a SELECT joining a table with its primary key with the result of a function, and it doesn't use the primary key index. How can I force to use the index? I tried with the FORCE instruction but it doesn't work.

[image]

**The select**

```
SELECT * FROM tb1 where id = get_last(25)
```

**Structure**

```
CREATE TABLE `tb1` (
    `id` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `prof` INT(11) NOT NULL,
    `start_date` DATETIME(6) NOT NULL,
    `end_date` DATETIME(6) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
    INDEX `IX_prof` (`prof`)
);

CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`%` FUNCTION `get_last`(prof int) RETURNS int(11)
BEGIN
    DECLARE id int(11);
    select a.id INTO id from tb1 a
    where a.prof = prof
    and a.end_date in (
        SELECT MAX(b.end_date) 
        FROM tb1 b
        WHERE b.prof = a.prof
    );
RETURN id;
END
```

Comment: Is there any particular reason for using a function instead of nested query?

Comment: If you ask why there is no "using index" in explain - that's because you select all columns and mysql can't get all values from index. You have using where and it means you're generally ok (though using that kind of fucntions isn't too good)

Comment: I think the problem is that the query doesn't use index, as there is `NULL` in possible_keys and key columns.

Comment: @matino in fact there is no NULLs. I changed the table definition to reflect that and the result is the same.

Comment: SELECT get_last(25) lasts 0 seconds, why using it as a join last more than 2 minutes?

Comment: @Alexey yes, it is the answer to the no "using index". Selecting only one column use the 'IX_prof' key as index, but... the SELECT continue to last more than 2 minutes :-( It should use the PRIMARY key, isn't it?

Comment: Declare your function as `DETERMINISTIC` (put the word `DETERMINISTIC` infront of the `BEGIN`). Or, preferable, don't use a function for that and calculate the value in a subquery (you can basically put the `select a.id from tb1 a...`-code where you currently use your function).

Comment: Putting the function code directly into the SELECT doesn't work, it lasts the same as using the function:
SELECT a.id
  FROM tbl1 a where a.id = (select b.id from tbl1 b
 where b.prof = a.prof
 and b.end_date in (
  SELECT MAX(c.end_date) 
  FROM tbl1 c 
  WHERE c.prof = b.prof
 )
  )    
But, @Solarflare, declaring the function as DETERMINISTIC works like a charm!!!! Select executed in 0 seconds!!!! Thx!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are working much too hard.  Toss the Function and simply say

```
SELECT  *
    FROM  tb1
    WHERE  prof = 25
    ORDER BY  end_date DESC
    LIMIT  1;
```

For further performance, replace your index on `prof` with

```
INDEX(prof, end_date)
```